# vstoolsforxamarin Installation Error

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, installation

I have been attempting to install Xamarin w/ Visual Studio via Xamarin's vstoolswithxamarin.exe installer. I have just installed Visual Studio in a fresh Windows 10 installation. I have about 75 gb available on the installation drive. After initiating the installation with the installer's default options selected, the installation sits for a very long time at "Configuring your system. This might take a while", then finally ends with the error "Setup Completed however not all features installed correctly. Optional Items. This operation returned because the timeout period expired." I have no 3rd party virus protection, and attached is a log file from an installation attempted with Windows Defender disabled.

[Log File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9OM-I7G0vMgaElEbEZxanJYUGs/view?usp=sharing)

As BytesGuy recommended, I checked the version information in Visual Studio and received the following output:

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015
Version 14.0.25123.00 Update 2
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.6.01038

Installed Version: Community

Visual Basic 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA499
Microsoft Visual Basic 2015

Visual C# 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA499
Microsoft Visual C# 2015

Visual C++ 2015   00322-20000-00000-AA499
Microsoft Visual C++ 2015

Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU   00322-20000-00000-AA499
Windows Phone SDK 8.0 - ENU

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   1.0
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)   14.1.11106.0
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015.1 (Beta8)

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2012.2   4.1.41102.0
For additional information, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=309563

ASP.NET Web Frameworks and Tools 2013   5.2.40314.0
For additional information, visit http://www.asp.net/

Common Azure Tools   1.7
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools   1.4
Microsoft Azure Mobile Services Tools

NuGet Package Manager   3.4.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit http://docs.nuget.org/.

PreEmptive Analytics Visualizer   1.2
Microsoft Visual Studio extension to visualize aggregated summaries from the PreEmptive Analytics product.

SQL Server Data Tools   14.0.60311.1
Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools

TypeScript   1.8.29.0
TypeScript tools for Visual Studio
```

If the Xamarin tools are there, I am missing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check if Xamarin was installed correctly by grabbing the version info from Visual Studio:

> Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio -> Copy Info

You should see the version of Xamarin near the end of the list:

[image: Visual Studio version info]

Alternatively, you can use the Xamarin.VisualStudio installer - if you email contact@xamarin.com we can send you the download link for this.

Comment: The Xamarin support team got right back to me after my email, and the Xamarin.VisualStudio installer seems to have done the trick right away. Thank you!